# How to create and add object to collection of a class

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have two entities - Movie and Review. I want to create a new review for a specific movie. Then add that review in the collection in the Movie entity. When I debug the code below, I can read the *movie* variable and see that it does indeed have this new review in its collections. But when I get the same movie again, the review collection is empty.

Movie

[image]

Review

[image]

Creating and adding the review

```
var movie = data.Movies.Find(5);

var newReview = new Review
{
   Content = "Example",
   MovieId = 5
};

movie.Reviews.Add(newReview);
data.Reviews.Add(newReview);
data.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: And how do you _"get the same movie again"_?

Comment: See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Comment: @GuruStron I get the movie the same way, using EF Core - `data.Movies.Find(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fetching the data again.

Based on your comment, you find the movie again using

`data.Movies.Find(5)`

However, this will not automatically bring the [related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) back with the movie.  EF Core requires by default to eagerly load those related entities using `.Include()`

To remedy the data fetching for your query it would look like this:

```
data.Movies
   .Include(m => m.Reviews)
   .FirstOrDefault(5)
```

If a movie could have zero reviews and you want to perform a true `LEFT JOIN`, then modify the above to:

```
data.Movies
   .Include(m => m.Reviews).DefaultIfEmpty()
   .FirstOrDefault(5)
```

Comment: The problem was solved with `.Include()`. Only I had to use `.FirstOrDefault()` after that because `.Find()` was giving me an error.

Comment: Thanks @FadoBagi!  I think that's a better choice.  Not sure why `Find` failed, but this is a much more accepted function to use instead.  I updated my answer.  Thanks!